# Directive not injecting html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive that displays a small blue box in a table when my value fee.pay is set to true. The table I'm in is a directive as well but I think we've done a good job sticking to each directives respective scope and syncing values between the two, though feel free to point out the smallest, "this could be causing something" issue.

here's the part of the table directive I'm working with, for what I'm doing this should be enough from this file but I need to show the whole file that's no problem.  table.html

```
<tr><div ng-if="$index > 0">
                    <div ng-if="defaultFee.Paid">
                        Paid
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="!defaultFee.Paid">
                        <input type="button" class="button button-light-blue button-xSmall-text button-w130" 
                                             ng-value="defaultFee.pay === undefined ? 'Calculate and Pay' : 'Cancel'"
                                             ng-click="calculateAndPay($index, defaultFee)" />
                        <input type="button" ng-click="stupidShit(defaultFee)" value="woooh" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr calculate-and-pay fee="defaultFee" project="project" ng-show="defaultFee.pay" index="$index" /></tr>
```

The js for this file is. grid.directive.js

```
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel : '=',
            fees    : '='
        },
            // calculate and pay handled in controller to utilize
            // the $state param to navigate to the calculation page
            function calculateAndPay(index, fee) {
                // if the passed fee is the initial major fee
                // go to the initial fee calculation page
                if ($.inArray(fee, $scope.locals.defaults) > -1 && index === 0) {
                    $state.go('^.^.fee.initial');
                }
                else {
                    // display the calculate and pay
                    // input and pdf link
                    if (fee.pay === undefined) {
                        fee.pay = true;
                    }
                    // hide the calculate and pay
                    // input and pdf link
                    else {
                        validator.clearValidation();
                        delete fee.pay;
                    }
                }
            }
        templateUrl: '/ng-src/components/projects/edit/fee-payment/fee-payment-grid.template.html'
```

The html for the directive that is not showing is. pay.template.html

The js for this directive is. pay.directive.js

```
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            fee     : '=',
            project : '=',
            index   : '=',
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope) {
            $scope.locals = {
                projectTypes : PROJECT_TYPES,
                feeTypes     : FEE_TYPES,
                payment      : {}
            }

        link: {
            post: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
                // scope functions
                scope.payFee = payFee;

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //saw in other questions similar to mine 
                //it gets hit when the ng-show value is changed but the 
                //the function show() doesn't do anything
                //if (attrs.hasOwnProperty("ngShow")) {
                //    scope.$watch("ngShow", function (value) {
                //        if (value) {
                //            elem.show();
                //            elem.removeClass('ng-hide');
                //        }
                //        else {
                //            elem.hide();
                //        }
                //    });
                //}

            templateUrl: '/ng-src/components/projects/edit/fee-payment/calculate-and-pay.template.html'
```

To give a quick run through.  In the table there is a button called 'Calculate and Pay' you can see the text for this in the ng-value in table.html.  When this is clicked the calculateAndPay() function is called in grid.directive.js. The first conditional, if ($.inArray(fee, $scope.locals.defaults) > -1 && index === 0), will not be hit, that's a different test case.  But what I'm trying to fix now will also affect that area if it's not fixed.  once in the else, the first condition changes the bit to true, this is the value that ng-show is watching (fee.pay = true).  Once the value has been changed then I am able to hit the link.post() function in pay.directive.js and I'm able to see when the values are changed every time.  I found it strange I couldn't view my innerHTML or elem.html() which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong with the template but I don't know what.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated and if I need to explain anything better please let me know.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is it at all possible for you to reduce this example? Can you create an illustrative example of the issue so that we would not need to understand a lot of business logic? Remove all the code branches that are not related to the issue at hand. If you want help (and expect to get it), at least make an effort to isolate the problem as much as possible? Right now, I need to use Ctrl+F just to find what function you are referring to

Comment: I knew I put too much up there. My plan was to work on a condensed example when I had more time.  I will though condense what's going on above, I didn't want to add too little but sadly I added too much haha I probably won't be able to come back to this till 6 though but I will condense what I have with some explanation to help guide along

Comment: You put *waaaay* too much. And, frankly, if you don't have time to invest in your own question, then why do you expect us to invest time in helping?

Comment: I wasted most of my trying to figure this out so I actually did invest time into my question, I just wrote it quickly.  And I don't want anyone to spend time on it at all, if they had come across something similar and have a suggestion that's all I'd like

Answer (score 0):

templateUrl was in the wrong place, I had it inside post() initially, now it's

```
link: {
        post: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // scope functions
            scope.payFee = payFee;
        },
        templateUrl: '/ng-src/components/projects/edit/fee-payment/calculate-and-pay.template.html'
}
```